# How to find and update a row in an Excel sheet based on a value in a column in another sheet?

Tags: excel, vba

Looking some guidance.  I have two excel sheets  (1) masterdata (2) Searchterms.

Searchterms contains a single column A with  StudentIDs.
Masterdata contains all data relating to students.

I've never used VBA before in excel so looking some guidance please

What i need to be able to do is take the first studentID from StudentIDs sheet (A1)  and search for it on the Masterdata sheet. If found then update the columns in that sheet (masterdata) with several pieces of information...  If not found then move onto the next StudentID in col A2 etc  on the StudentIds sheet.

```
Sub FindMatchingValue() 
Dim i As Integer
  Dim strValueToFind As String

    strValueToFind = Worksheets("StudentID").Range("A1").Value
    For i = 1 To 500
        If Cells(i, 1).Value = strValueToFind Then
            MsgBox ("Found value on row " & i)
            'update row i col B  = 'new name' - found in StudentID sheet col B
            'update row i col C  = 'new class number '- found in StudentID sheet col C
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Next i

    MsgBox ("Value not found in the range!")
End Sub
```

**workbook contains two worksheets** namely 
**masterdata worksheet** 
with columns....

- Col A StudentID
- Col B Name
- Col C Class Number
- Col D Enrol Date
- Col E Start Date
- Col F Student Loan
- Col G Comments
- COL H Last edited

  normally about 5000 rows in this sheet

and

**searchterms worksheet**
with columns.....

- Col A StudentID
- Col B Name
- Col C Class Number
- Col D Comment

  normally about 1-20 rows in this sheet

Comment: Where is the code you have already tried and what problems did you have with it?

Comment: I'm brand new to VB and just starting out on this so not alot making sense.....

Comment: Where is the new data used to update the "master data" sheet?

Comment: hi Tim added some more detail thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's something you can try. We have 2 major jobs here.

1. Find the match. Of course, you can use `For Loop` as in your attempt but, let's take advantage of Excel's built in method, [`Find`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.find). Find method returns a Range object, meaning it will return the range in *masterdata* sheet that contains the *student ID*.

   ```
   Dim sID As Range, whattofind As Range
   Dim mSh As Worksheet, sSh As Worksheet

   Set mSh = Worksheets("masterdata") '// you can adjust to suit //
   Set sSh = Worksheets("searchitems")

   Set whattofind = sSh.Range("A1")

   With mSh
     '// here you use the Find Method of the Range Object //
     Set sID = .Range("A:A").Find(What:=whattofind.Value2, _
                                  After:=.Range("A" & .Rows.Count))
     '// take note that we supplied the After argument //
     '// that is to cover the entire range from top to bottom //
   End With
   ```
2. Update the records. Since we already found Range that contains the *student ID*, we just have to update some columns. To do that, we'll use Excel's built in method, [`Offset`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.offset). And take note that we need to do it several times since we have multiple entries in *searchitems* sheet. So we will use a `For Loop` too.

   ```
   Dim sID As Range, whattofind As Range, i As Long
   Dim mSh As Worksheet, sSh As Worksheet

   Set mSh = Worksheets("masterdata") '// you can adjust to suit //
   Set sSh = Worksheets("searchitems")


   For i = 1 To 500  '// depends on your list //
     Set whattofind = sSh.Range("A" & i)
     With mSh
       Set sID = .Range("A:A").Find(What:=whattofind.Value2, _
                                    After:=.Range("A" & .Rows.Count))
       If Not sID Is Nothing Then '// check if a match is found //
         '// just play around and adjust on how many columns you need updated //
         sID.Offset(, 2) = whattofind.Offset(, 2) '// here we update Class number //
         sID.Offset(, 6) = whattofind.Offset(, 3) '// here we update Comments //
       End If
     End With
     '// reset your ranges //
     Set sID = Nothing
     Set whattofind = Nothing
   Next
   ```

I hope this helps to get you started.

Comment: Perfect. and thanks for the  inline explanation this has really helped me move forward!